# How to jump to a element in a different part of the page?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a nav bar, it the nav bar I have some links. when I click on one of the links I want to jump to a specific part of the page.

I tried to implement the 'jumping motion' for the "pricing" button. here is the nav bar code::

```
const NavigationBar = () => {
  // fix: how to send the user to a part of a page when the click something in the header?
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar bg="dark" fixed="top" variant="dark">
        <Container>
          <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Bowsky</Navbar.Brand>
          <Nav className="me-auto">
            <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#features">Features</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Pricing</Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    </>
  );
};
```

here is the code for the pricing component::

```
const Grid = () => {
  const caroselData = [
    {
      imgSrc: "https://picsum.photos/900/400",
      title: "title 1",
      description: "description 1"
    },
    {
      imgSrc: "https://picsum.photos/900/400",
      title: "title 2",
      description: "description 2"
    }
  ];
  return (
    <Container style={{ paddingTop: "100px" }}>
      <SimpleCarousel data={caroselData} />
      <Features />
      <Pricing id="pricing" />
      <FrequentlyAskedQuestions />
    </Container>
  );
};
```

here is the code repo::
Note: the tabs to look at are 'Grid.js' and 'NavigationBar.js'

https://codesandbox.io/s/bosky-active-ow4qs7?file=/src/Components/Grid.js:231-730

I also tried to use react-scroll but I didn't have any luck either. it actually throws an error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that the [document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Creating_hyperlinks#document_fragments) you want to link to — in your case an element in the HTML resulting from the render of `<Pricing />` — has an `id` attribute set. Currently you're passing an `id` **prop** to the `<Pricing />` **react component** (which doesn't actually seem to accept any props), not actually setting an **HTML attribute** anywhere.

You can use your browser's devtools to find the actual HTML tag you want the scroll to jump to, then you'll just need to add the proper `id` attribute to that element in your code.